# Confuse about ParentRef in QuickBooks Online

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

In my quickbooks online application, I want to create a class. But it asks me for a ParentRef. 
I understand what it should be. But not sure how and where to create it?

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

ParentRef is an optional attribute.

Please refer docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/class

You can create a class without ParentRef. After creation, you'll get the Id from the service. You can use(as ParentRef) that ID to create a new child class.

For ex -

```
<Class xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" sparse="false">
   <Name>ClassJUnitInputCreateRead-1373589504207</Name>
   <ParentRef>100100000000000321236</ParentRef>
</Class>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Talking Quickbooks SDK experience (qbXML,qbFC), and not specifically online api.

When creating a new item, you can create it as a subitem of another item. In this case, you will have to specify the `FullName` or the `listID` of the item that you want to be the parent. (Also, when getting an item (object) from Quickbooks, it will return the item, with its `ListID` and `FullName`, as well as the `ListID` and `FullName` of its parent, if any.

Comment: In Other words, you cant "think up" the parent Item. it needs to be an existing item in quickbooks. If you need to create a new parent, first then create the aprent item, and upon creatinon, get the qbdetermined ListID and FullName, then us this info, tp specify in the parentRef.